# Priorize /server-status front another .htaccess rewrite rules in apache2

Tags: apache-2.2

It's possible to priorize /server-status front another rewrite rules? For example the next ones don't let the /server-status works:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !\.
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I have to add this to the .htaccess to don't enter to the php project:

```
RewriteRule ^server-status$ - [L]
```

With mod_pagespeed of google, their statistics page works without adding them to the project .htaccess: /mod_pagespeed_statistics

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/configuration

---

My mod_status.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_status.c>

  <Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status

    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all

    Allow from 127.0.0.1 
    # My allowed ips here
  </Location>

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand your question correctly, but you can add these two lines on top of your `.htaccess` file to avoid usage of other, following rules.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /server-status
RewriteRule ^ - [END]
```